# Using readLines() and strsplit() in R correctly to extract data from a file

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I am trying to read a big dataset with many files (no .csv or .txt) into R and have to use the readLines() function because the files aren't formatted in any way, R could read as table. The data looks like this:

```
       Versuchsflaeche  1011  Parzelle  1  Baumnummer  6    30

                                 Scheibenhoehe¹ (m)
 Stock- Alter Jahr  Hoehe   0.00   0.30   1.30   6.60  11.80  16.00  18.00  20.00


   1     4   1935   0.44   0.91   0.44                                          
   2     5   1936   0.80   1.47   1.00                                          
   3     6   1937   1.18   2.06   1.59                                          
   4     7   1938   1.48   2.44   1.97   0.40                                   
   5     8   1939   1.95   2.56   2.18   0.91
```

.. and so on. So when I read the file, I get a character-variable where each string is one line. In fact every file contains 6 tables, so I started identifying the relevant parts with grep() for the beginning and end of each table. Now I want to combine all the tables of the file into a data.frame, but I am struggling with the right way two use strsplit(). The code looks like this:

```
  for( ..
      dat<-readLines(directory, files[i])

      x<-dat[grep(identify, dat)[1]:(grep(identify2)]
      x<-[-(2:3]
      all.data<-data.frame(lapply(x, function(x) strsplit(x,"\\s"))
```

In fact, it doesn't work the way I want it to. My goal is that at the end there's a data.frame with the part over the numbers as row.names and the rest as single number values and NAs.

I would be very happy about any help!

Comment: unless you're doing this to satisfy some intellectual curiosity, ime you'll be much better off formatting the data using some other tool first (python, awk, sed, perl, etc)

Comment: Agreed. Transform the data to CSV and then load the CSV.

Comment: Hm..I would do it, if i had any experience with these languages. Shoulnd't R be able to do this aswell?

Comment: Please give us an example of input file contents and output contents.

Comment: As a starting point: Assuming `txt` contains you example data (use e.g. `txt <- readLines(n = 11, con = "clipboard") ` to paste it from the windows clipboard) - `do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(strsplit(txt[7:11], "\\s+"), function(sp) { as.data.frame(t(sp), stringsAsFactors = F) }))` will get you a data frame. You need the `plyr` package installed.